# Can we handle bad elasticsearch input as string?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

I have some data, and some of predefined mapping, so if i write some text to object, it of course will drop me and error that it could not map concrete value into object.
But is there anyway to handle this, by moving this error concrete value into other field in the same document? Take the same name of field of that object, add suffix, make its type text or maybe keyword and put that bad text(for object) to there?

Answer (score 1):

not natively, no sorry to say. you'd need to capture this error in your client and then run that logic there

you can use something like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html to ignore the bad data, but that simple drops it

Comment: Thanks will think about that